# How to search for substrings

Tags: java, string, loops

I'm looking for patterns like "tip" and "top" in the string -- length-3, starting with 't' and ending with 'p'. The goal is to return a string where for all such words, the middle letter is gone. So for example, "tipXtap" yields "tpXtp".

So far, I've thought about using recursion, and the replace() method, but am not sure if that is the best way to approach this problem.

Here is my code thus far:

```
String result = ""; 
if(str.length() < 3) 
    return str; 

for(int i = 0; i <= str.length() - 2; i++){ 
    if(str.charAt(i) == 't' && str.charAt(i + 2) == 'p'){
       str.replaceAll(str.substring(i + 1, i + 2), ""); 
    } 
    return str; 
}

return str;
```

Comment: Regex will help you ;)

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to use Regex in tandem with the replace() or the replaceAll() methods. Couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What programming language do you want the solution in?

Comment: @ShivanshuGoyal There is a `java` tag on the question

Comment: @allmvp96 - please try to title your questions descriptively. Think of how to title it so that someone who was interested in helping you on a string pattern recognition problem in Java would see it and know to click on it. Also, please include your code so far, with a description of what you've tried and where you're stuck. If you haven't tried anything yet, it's usually too early to post on Stack Overflow

Comment: Here is my code thus far:

Comment: String result = "";
  if(str.length() < 3) return str;

  for(int i = 0; i <= str.length() - 2; i++){
    if(str.charAt(i) == 't' && str.charAt(i + 2) == 'p'){
     str.replaceAll(str.substring(i + 1, i + 2), "");
    }
    return str;
  } 
  return str;

Comment: @ShivanshuGoyal java

Answer (score 2):

Use this Java code:

```
String str = "tipXtap";
str = str.replaceAll("t.p", "tp");
```

This uses [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and the [String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) function. The `.` (dot) character is a [regex metacharacter that matches any single character](https://regexone.com/lesson/wildcards_dot).

Comment: Ahh, didnt know that little fact. I will try it now.

Comment: Please keep in mind that you need to capture return value of `replaceAll`.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, fixed

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this.

1. Convert the String to a char array.
2. Use if conditions to validate first and third letter from the first letter. First look whether a char of a String is T and then check the char two chars away is a 'p'. You have to do this inside a loop traversing the char array.
3. If the validation condition is true, remove the middle element. You will have to move the element in the char array.
4. Convert the char array to a String and return it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, that def can work. But I think there is a simpler way of going about this.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes I also think so. Just gave an idea :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a JavaScript solution to this problem using regular expressions:

```
foo = 'tipXtop'
foo.replace(/t\wp/g, 'tp')
```

The `\w` regex operator matches a word character like a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or _.

The `g` regex flag will match all instances of the regex in the string.

Comment: Question is for Java (see tags).

Comment: I know, but this is a correct JavaScript solution. There is no reason for you to downvote.